# /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/ doesn't exist

Tags: hibernate, 23.10, policykit

I was trying to fix hibernation on my laptop with Ubuntu 23.10. A [guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/) suggested to edit `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. I did it and then ran `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`. Now I am trying to do it once more but `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/` doesn't exist anymore. How can I restore it?